# Converting a 3D tensor of image blocks into 2D image on TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I have an image of size `256 x 256`  divided into non-overlapping blocks of size `32 x 32` and arranged as a 3D tensor of size `[64, 32, 32]`. Here, `64` is the number of `32 x 32` blocks in the image. The 64 blocks are arranged in such a way that the first 8 blocks form the first row, the next 8 the second row and so on.

I want to know if there is a way to construct the full image given the image blocks on TensorFlow without using loops. There is a related function `tf.batch_to_space`, however it does not exactly do what is required. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def reconstruct(x):
  x = tf.reshape(x, [8, 8, 32, 32])
  x = tf.transpose(x, [0, 2, 1, 3])  # x.shape is [8, 32, 8, 32]
  x = tf.reshape(x, [256, 256])      # Because tf tensor is row-major.
  return x
```